# I want to get particular key wise value without For Loop use

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

```
"Setting":  "[{"WIDTH":"150",
      "HEIGHT":"140", 
      "IS_REQUIRED":"YES",
      "TOP_MARGIN":"30" , 
      "LEFT_MARGIN":"80",
      "LINEBREAK":"NO",
      "DEFAULT":"NULL"
    }]"
```

Comment: When I use WIDTH THEN GET VALUE 150.

Comment: And why you used loop in your question, what you tried with loop?

Comment: You'll have to explain more about your problem. Are you having trouble instantiating an NSDictionary from this? Are you trying to get all values of width from an array of similar values? As it stands this is not easy to answer.

Comment: I already use this method now What can I do...

Comment: @iPhoneGuru: now you added "Setting:", this makes all answers incorrect. **Never edit your original question, once answered**

Comment: Sorry But This is Real question ... I solved one time this .. After than I need help

Comment: @iphoneguru please clarify what you have and what you need to get - do you have more than 1 dictionary with this same structure?

Comment: I need, When I use particular key use then get Value .. Like as I use WIDTH THEN GET 150 ... ONE BY ONE

Comment: @iPhoneGuru: Do you have  arrays of objects that contains WIDTH?

Comment: NO .. I'M GETTING THIS VALUE IN DICTIONARY ..

Comment: [mtmDic valueForKey:@"field_setting"]  using this I got this Value...
[{"WIDTH":"150",
      "HEIGHT":"140", 
      "IS_REQUIRED":"YES",
      "TOP_MARGIN":"30" , 
      "LEFT_MARGIN":"80",
      "LINEBREAK":"NO",
      "DEFAULT":"NULL"
    }]
Now I Wanna that I use particular value using key Like As ... I use WIDTH THEN GET VALUE 150.

Comment: @iPhoneGuru:Does this work?  `NSLog(@"%@", mtmDict[@"field_setting"][0][@"WIDTH"]);`

Comment: I already try this...

Comment: @iPhoneGuru: what error ? is it null. Then try NSLog(@"%@", [mtmDict[@"field_setting"] class]);

Comment: yes it's working and I'm getting  " __NSCFString ".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26775/discussion-between-iphone-guru-and-anoop-vaidya)

Comment: @iPhoneGuru: that shows you dont have array or dictionary, Refer to Martin's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it as :

```
 NSString *string=yourDict[@"WIDTH"];
```

Or,

```
NSString *string=[yourDict objectForKey:@"WIDTH"];
```

Check [NSDictionary Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and new [Objective-C literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

And please please please Start learning Objective-C, may be from Apple Documentation.

---

Edit:

As you changed your question and added "Setting:".

Now you need to use :

```
NSString *string=yourDict[@"Setting"][@"WIDTH"];
```

EDIT 1:

I think you have array of objects. Each object contains set of `WIDTH`, `LINEBREAK` etc.

```
NSString *string=yourDict[@"Setting"][0][@"WIDTH"];
```

Comment: I Have also in Dictionary ... But After One time get .... I need One by One Value ....

Comment: @iPhoneGuru: Setting is a key and WIDTH is another key, right? Please explain fully, what you want

Comment: I USE THIS METHOD BUT GETTING "NULL" VALUE

Comment: @iPhoneGuru: try my edit 1 answer, and tell if any error.

Comment: @iPhoneGuru: You are unable to express your rquirement, then how can anyone help you.

Comment: I have done this ....
NSDictionary *myDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[mtmDic valueForKey:@"field_setting"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

Answer (score 1):

Try it :

```
    NSArray *itemObjects = (NSArray *) [resultDict objectForKey:@"Setting"];
    for (int i=0;i<[itemObjects count];i++) {
            NSDictionary *rssDict=[itemObjects objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *str1=[rssDict objectForKey:@"WIDTH"];
            NSString *str2=[rssDict objectForKey:@"HEIGHT"];
            NSString *str3=[rssDict objectForKey:@"IS_REQUIRED"];
            NSString *str4=[rssDict objectForKey:@"LEFT_MARGIN"];

     }
```

Comment: I see a for loop here.

Comment: IT'S NOT WORKING AND ONE OTHRE THING I WANNA GET VALUE WITHOUT FOR LOOP

Comment: Who UPVOTED this, Can't even see what the question says **NO FOR LOOP*. I suggest you to use while loop instead, or even a do-while, recusive method, or goto cycle.

Comment: @SAMIT RATHOD.... I Have done ...

NSDictionary *myDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[mtmDic valueForKey:@"field_setting"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

Answer (score 1):

Your `mtmDict[@"field_setting"]` is not an array or dictionary, but a ***string*** with JSON data. You can use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert that string to an array and access the value:

```
NSString *jsonString = mtmDict[@"field_setting"];
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:NULL];

NSLog(@"%@", jsonArray[0][@"WIDTH"]);
```

Comment: +1 Yes you got it right, it took 1 hour for me to understand. This is called knowledge and experience.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Thank you. I'm just glad that I could post an answer before the question is closed :-)

Comment: Then you need +2 from my side :) how to do that, posting in meta :D

Comment: @Martin R .. I have done this ...    NSDictionary *myDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[mtmDic valueForKey:@"field_setting"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

Comment: @iPhoneGuru: That looks like the same code, only combined into one line. Did it work?

Comment: @iPhoneGuru: The JSON seems to contain an array (see my code), so you should do `NSArray *myArray = [NSJSONSerialization ...]`.

Comment: @iPhoneGuru: Did you make any progress? Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[youDic objectForKey:@"Setting"] objectForKey:@"WIDTH"]);
```

**OR**

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[[[youDic objectForKey:@"Setting"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"WIDTH"]);
```

Comment: I have done...
NSDictionary *myDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[mtmDic valueForKey:@"field_setting"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];